# How to fix the: ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3552 into shape (296,296,12)

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I plan to create a simple crypto price prediction tool using a combined model of CNN and LSTM models. Here are my deep learning model and the process that I used to train the model:

Model:

```
def define_models():
    global combined_model
    n_features = 12
    n_timesteps = 296

    # Step 1: Define input layers for CNN and LSTM models
    cnn_input = Input(shape=(n_timesteps, n_features))
    lstm_input = Input(shape=(n_timesteps, n_features))

    # Step 2: Define the layers for the CNN model
    cnn_model = Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu')(cnn_input)
    cnn_model = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(cnn_model)
    cnn_model = Flatten()(cnn_model)

    # Step 3: Define the layers for the LSTM model
    lstm_model = LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=True)(lstm_input)
    lstm_model = LSTM(units=64)(lstm_model)

    # Step 4: Combine the CNN and LSTM outputs
    combined_model = concatenate([cnn_model, lstm_model])
    combined_model = Dense(units=64, activation='relu')(combined_model)
    combined_model = Dense(units=2)(combined_model)  # Two output nodes for high and low prices

    # Step 5: Create the combined model
    combined_model = Model(inputs=[cnn_input, lstm_input], outputs=combined_model)

    # Step 6: Compile the combined model
    combined_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
```

Training process:

```
def training_process():
    global df8hour
    global df
    global actual_labels, predicted_labels

    start_row = 0
    i = 1
    # Step 5: Define the training loop
    while True:
        if(start_row+557 >= 410021):
            print("Reached to the end!")
            break

        df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/pricedata1.csv', skiprows=range(0, start_row), nrows= 296, names=['timestamp', 'open_price', 'high_price', 'low_price', 'price', 'close_time', 'volume', 'interval','sma', 'rsi', 'macd', 'bollinger_bands'])
        if df.empty:
            print("Data is Over!")
            break

        df['interval'] = df['interval'].str.replace('1h', '60')
        df['interval'] = df['interval'].str.replace('4h', '240')
        df['interval'] = df['interval'].str.replace('m', '')

        # Preprocessing the data
        #df.sort_values('timestamp', inplace=True)
        #df.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)

        # fill none values with 0
        df8hour = df.fillna(0)

        # getting 2 hours label data points in 15 minutes for validating
        label_df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/pricedata1.csv', skiprows=range(0, start_row+553), nrows=4, names=['timestamp', 'open_price', 'high_price', 'low_price', 'price', 'close_time', 'volume', 'interval','sma', 'rsi', 'macd', 'bollinger_bands'])
        label_df = label_df[['low_price', 'high_price']]
        label_df = label_df.fillna(0)

        # data normalization
        #df8hour = normalization(df8hour, ['open_price', 'high_price', 'low_price', 'price', 'volume', 'sma', 'rsi', 'macd'])
        #price_df = normalization(price_df, ['high_price', 'low_price'])

        #technical indicator calculation
        calculate_technical_indicators()

        input_data = df8hour.values.astype(float)               
        pricelabel = label_df.values.astype(float)

        # repeat labels to align the numbers to input timesteps
        pricelabel_repeated = np.repeat(pricelabel, 296 // 4, axis=0)

        # Reshaping
        input_data_reshaped = np.reshape(input_data, (input_data.shape[0], 296, input_data.shape[1]))

        # Step 7: Train the model
        checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='model_checkpoint.h5', monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True)
        combined_model.fit([expanded_data,expanded_data], pricelabel_repeated, epochs=10, batch_size=32, callbacks=[checkpoint])

        print(f"Epoch completed: {i}")

        # Calculate RMSE
        predictions = combined_model.predict(input_data)
        rmse = calculate_rmse(predictions, pricelabel_repeated)
        print(f'RMSE value: {rmse}')

        # add to the label lists
        for i in range(len(pricelabel_repeated)):
          actual_labels.append(pricelabel_repeated[i])
          predicted_labels.append(predictions[i])

        time.sleep(5)

        start_row+=296


    # Step 8: Save the trained model
    combined_model.save('trained_model.h5')
```

In the above code `pricedata1.csv` is a files containing price data  movement data of BTC/USDT. It includes these features including timestamp, open price, high price, low_price, close price, close_time, volume and interval.  This is the problem that I'm facing:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-3325f837e0ae> in <cell line: 255>()
    253 
    254 define_models()
--> 255 training_process()
    256 show_graph(actual_labels, predicted_labels)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
     55 
     56     try:
---> 57         return bound(*args, **kwds)
     58     except TypeError:
     59         # A TypeError occurs if the object does have such a method in its

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3552 into shape (296,296,12)
```

Why can't I reshape this the input_data array? Is there anything I'm doing wrong? How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When you call:

```
# Reshaping  
input_data_reshaped = np.reshape(input_data, (input_data.shape[0], 296, input_data.shape[1]))
```

You end up trying to reshape your input_data, which is size [3552], into [296, 296, 12], but you original input_data shape was only [296, 12] (296 * 12 = 3552)

Comment: how can I fix this? Are there any other ways to convert this 2D array to a 3D array?

Comment: When you reshape your data to (input_data.shape[0], 296, input_data.shape[1]), it might just need to be (1, input_data.shape[0], input_data.shape[1]), where the 1 would mean a single element. But you should have more elements to be able to train properly a model. If i understood your data correctly it is something like that

Comment: Reading your code in more detail, you are reading your data as you train your model? Even if you want to do that you do a custom training and not use the fit function. I believe, since you are new to this, that you should load your data all at once (if you dataset is not that large), give a look at this [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/lstm-how-to-train-neural-networks-to-write-like-lovecraft-e56e1165f514) and try not to copy the code, understand what he is doing and do something similar with your data